# Joomla file restore after crash

Tags: mysql, database, joomla

Been wresteling with Joomla for a customer. I installed an update from 2.5.19 to 3.2.2 and it crashed. Couldn't log into the backend anymore or anything. 
After putting the backup files back on the server it still kept giving errors and leaving me unable to log in.

I now have re-installed Joomla 3.2.2 and want to restore just the content (articles, components and modules).

Does anyone know where I can find the files that I should put back on the server? If I import the entire administrator folder it crashes again..

Answer (score 0):

By *files* you probably mean *database entries*, as joomla contents are stored in the database. If however you do mean files then just put them in the corresponding folders e.g. `images` in 2.5 to `images` in 3.2 etc. I also assume that you probably didn't follow the correct procedure for upgrading your installation. That said I suggest taking a look at the following:

- [Upgrading from an existing version](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2%3aUpgrading_from_an_existing_version)
- [What are the major differences between 2.5 and 3?](http://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_3_FAQ)
- [Practical Guide Upgrade Joomla 2.5 to Joomla 3.x](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=710&t=793171)
- [Upgrade from Joomla 2.5 to Joomla 3](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla-video/jooml25-to-joomla3/)

Comment: You're right. I didn't follow all the steps as stated. Thought I could just update the version and then update any necessary updates for plug-ins or extentions..

Thanks for the links!